# Eclipse Install new extension issues

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am working with Eclipse 3.3.1.1, when try to install an extension I go to help -> Software Updates -> Find And Install...

then i get the next message:
Requested operation cannot be performed because it would invalidate the current configuration, See details for more info...

Details:
Platform configuration has been modified outside this program. A restart is recommended.

Every time I try I get the same error even if I restart eclipse and my equipment as well.

Comment: Try restarting eclipse with the -clean option.  Won't solve the problem but it might clean up the cached configuration a bit.

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of Eclipse?  I'd recommend upgrading.

Comment: Company policies, i cannot upgrade.